# How can you extract each item of the path of any url with JavaScript and/or Regexs?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I'm looking for a way to analyse each part of an url.

For example I have these URL:

```
gs://myproject.appspot.com/soundtracks/track-title.mp3
gs://myproject.appspot.com/videos/video-title.mpg
soundtracks/track-title.mp3
videos/video-title.mpg
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zra2DCd0DnY
https://youtu.be/QtSXxtVkR24
https://www.instagram.com/p/CFaxzamnNI
```

I need to identify:

- the protocole: gs:// or none = internal, http(s):// = external
- the domaine: ie, if it is [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) or youtu.be I will use the last match as the id
- each component of the path: ie, if the media is in soundtracks i launch the audio tracks player and if it is in videos I launch the video player

I tested the simple Regex (JavaScript) :

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.%:\(\)~]+)/gi
```

It takes each set of characters usually used in urls, except separators / = ? as a match.

Result: https://regex101.com/r/eG0vW1/10

It is not bad. However I'm not experienced at all with this and I fear that there could be edge cases. Is it safe to use?

Comment: what if your local folder has a "." in it?

Comment: dots are part of the characters accepted in the [a-zA-Z0-9_\-.%:\(\)~] chain

Comment: Yes, of course they are!
How do you get from a URL to it's parts?
A URL doesn't have to be in English (and I'm not talking about 127.0.0.1, for example).
By the way, you should show your work, some samples and expected output HERE and not [just] off-site.
How about splitting by `/`?
And what about port?
You've mentioned `?`query (also: `=` and `&`).
Also, "#"...
I'm refreshing/reading:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL
added: uppercase/lowercase (that you ignore) are important for filenames.

Comment: and up the directory tree: `../`.

Comment: To know what to launch, you should inspect the extension of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you use JavaScript `URL()` constructor function supported by modern browsers (not IE):

```
const url = new URL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zra2DCd0DnY');
const relative_url = new URL('/videos/video-title.mpg', 'https://example.net');
const protocol = url.protocol; // 'https:', with final :.
const domain = url.hostname;
const path = url.pathname;
const path_components = path.split('/');
const params = url.searchParams;
const youtube_id = params.get('v');
// Iterate all search params:
// (not necessarily supported by your browser)
for (const [key, value] of params) {
    // do something with key and value.
}
// Or:
params.forEach(function(value, key){
    // do something with key and value.
});
```

You will notice, that, for `gc:` `url.pathname` includes what could be expected in `url.hostname`, but, taking into account the nature of `gc:` links, this is a feature, not a bug.

Further reading: https://dmitripavlutin.com/parse-url-javascript/.